# An equiareal map that is not a local isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

Could you give an example of an equiareal map that is not a local isometry?

$$$$

---

$$$$

A local diffeomorphism $f : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is equiareal if and only if, for any surface patch $\sigma (u, v)$ on $S_1$, the first fundamental forms $$E_1du^2 + 2F_1dudv + G_1dv^2 \ \text{ and } \ E_2du^2 + 2F_2dudv + G_2dv^2$$ of the patches $\sigma$ on $S_1$ and $f \circ \sigma$ on $S_2$ satisfy $$E_1G_1− F^2_1 = E_2G_2 − F^2_2$$

$$$$

---

$$$$

A local diffeomorphism $f : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is a local isometry if and only if, for any surface patch $\sigma_1$ of $S_1$, the patches $\sigma_1$ and $f \circ \sigma_1$ of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, have the same first fundamental form.

Answer (score 2):

$$  (x,y) \mapsto (x+y,y) $$ in the ordinary plane

Comment: We have $$E_1=\|f_x\|^2=1, F_1=f_x \cdot f_y=0, G_1=\|f_y\|^2=1$$ $$E_2=\|f_x\|^2=1, F_2=f_x \cdot f_y=1, G_2=\|f_y\|^2=2$$ 
$$E_1G_1-F_1^2=1, \ E_2G_2-F_2^2= 2-1=1$$ So the map is equiareal. The first funamental forms are $$dx^2+dy^2$$ and $$dx^2+dxdy+2dy^2$$ so they are not equal. Thus the map is not a local isometry. $$$$ Is this correct?

Comment: @MaryStar yes. If the map is in the plane and linear, as both Andrew and i gave, isometry means orthogonal matrix, area preserving means determinant $\pm 1.$ In $\mathbb R^3,$ a linear map isometric still means orthogonal matrix, but determinant $\pm 1$ means preserving the volume. You may have studied the Jacobian matrix for change of variable in integrals; that is exactly what this is talking about, not distorting the area/volume.

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: Do we not have to consider also a surface patch $\sigma$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar sure, here is a good one. Start with the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ but without the north or south pole. Map this to the round cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ by $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x / \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}, y / \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} , z)$ This preserves area.

Comment: Why do we consider at the beginning the unit sphere **without the north or south pole** ?

Comment: because that would allow $x^2 + y^2 = 0$

Comment: Why would that allow? I got stuck right now...

Comment: the north and south poles are $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$

Comment: So, when we consider the unit sphere with the north and south pole, the map wouldn't be 1-1, right? $$$$ Btw... I wish you a Happy New Year!! :-)

Comment: Or doesn't that mean this?

Comment: I got stuck right... Is $\sigma(x,y,z)=(x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z)$ ? Which is then $f(\sigma)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $S_{1} = S_{2} = \mathbf{R}^{2}$, and define $f(x, y) = (ax, by)$ for some positive real numbers $a$ and $b$. Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is $f$:

1. Area-preserving?
2. A local isometry?

If you'd like compact examples, it's straightforward to adapt this idea to maps between tori.

Comment: We have $$E_1=\|f_x\|^2=1, F_1=f_x \cdot f_y=0, G_1=\|f_y\|^2=1$$ $$E_2=\|f_x\|^2=a^2, F_2=f_x \cdot f_y=0, G_2=\|f_y\|^2=b^2$$ 
So that $f$ is area-preserving it must hold $$E_1G_1-F_1^2=E_2G_2-F_2^2 \Rightarrow 1=ab$$ $$$$ So that $f$ is a local isometry it must hold that $a=b=1$. $$$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Do we not have to consider also a surface patch $\sigma$ ?

Comment: The map $f$ _is_ a surface patch $\sigma:U \to S$, for the surface $S = \mathbf{R}^{2}$ using $U = \mathbf{R}^{2}$ as coordinate domain.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Which is $\sigma$ and which is $f(\sigma )$ ?